# Adding parameters to the WHERE clause of a SQL query

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, odbc

I'm using ADO.NET to connect to an Oracle DB through ODBC. Everything is working fine, besides binding parameters with a simple SQL query:

```
Connection.Open();
IDbCommand command = Connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT length FROM activity_type WHERE name = :name_of_activity";
var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
parameter.ParameterName = ":name_of_activity";
parameter.Value = "Short_break";
command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
int result = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
Connection.Close();
```

It always returns 0 results (a null from `ExecuteScalar()` - the same from a reader). But if I'd put a straightforward SQL query like this: `command.CommandText = "SELECT length FROM activity_type WHERE name = 'Short_break'"` it would work like a charm. Whats more, I used similar constructions all over the code for `INSERT INTO` clauses, and they were OK.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the docs for [`OdbcCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.parameters(v=VS.100).aspx):

> When CommandType is set to Text, the .NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC does not support passing named parameters to an SQL statement or to a stored procedure called by an OdbcCommand. In either of these cases, use the question mark (?) placeholder. For example:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
> ```

In other words, your code should look like this:

```
Connection.Open();
IDbCommand command = Connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT length FROM activity_type WHERE name = ?";
var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
parameter.Value = "Short_break";
command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
int result = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
Connection.Close();
```

(You should probably be considering using `using` statements, mind you... otherwise if this throws an exception, you won't be closing the connection.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've tried the '?' placeholder before, with no luck. Still the same result. Named parameters work in every other part of the code. I've extracted the code from the project, originally `Connection.Close()` is in a `finally` clause.

Comment: @M_F: Is this genuinely an `OdbcCommand`? It's hard to tell from the fairly generic code given. Unfortunately different providers support different forms of parameterized queries. Have you tried looking at your database logs to see what's getting through?

Comment: Yes it is an OdbcCommand. Connection is created as a `IdbConnection Connection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=oracle; UID=xxx; PWD=xxx");`. I try to get to the logs, thanks.

Comment: @M_F: Have you tried explicitly setting the command type to Text? I wouldn't expect that to make a difference, but you never know...

Answer (score 0):

From what you're describing the problem can only be in the parameter.

Maybe some kind of strange mixup like between varchar and nvarchar on SQL Server, in other words try setting the datatype explicitely.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line:

```
parameter.ParameterName = ":name_of_activity";
```

to

```
parameter.ParameterName = "name_of_activity";
```

In other words remove colon character