# How to get value from drop down list box

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

What I want is to get the value from the selected item in the drop down list, and use it to query (select table) in a button click event.

```
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBcon))
            {

               SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_WinApps_FileHeader");
               sqlCommand.Connection = con;

               SqlDataReader read = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

                GridView1.DataSource = read;
                GridView1.DataBind();


            }
        }
    }

  <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem>ER00 - File Header</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>ER01 - Expense Report Trans</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>ER02 - Expense Report Item Trans</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>ER03 - Expense Report Item Tax Trans</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>ER04 - Expense Report Item</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Or

```
DropDownList1.Text;
```

Or

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx) property of `DropDownList`. To see how to add parameter to the select query in where clause see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535327/adding-parameters-to-the-where-clause-of-a-sql-query).

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sel = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
  //  if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
  //  {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBcon))
        {

            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_WinApps_FileHeader");
            sqlCommand.Connection = con;
            SqlDataReader read = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataSource = read;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    //}
}
```

Comment: where can I put that line?

Comment: Also remove that if(SelectedIndex == 1) condition.
that condition does not make any sense, given you want to use the SelectedValue in your SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`SelectedValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx) property.

> Gets the value of the selected item in the list control, or selects
>   the item in the list control that contains the specified value.

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Like;

```
string val = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBcon))
{
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_WinApps_FileHeader");
    sqlCommand.Connection = con;

    SqlDataReader read = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

    GridView1.DataSource = read;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

If you want to use it as a parameter in your `SqlCommand`, you can use it like;

```
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl_WinApps_FileHeader WHERE val = @val");
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithVAlue("@val", val);
sqlCommand.Connection = con;
SqlDataReader read = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
```